# In Supernatural, why don't the angels always use their true forms?

Tags: supernatural, lucifer

I just finished Season 5 of Supernatural and one thing was bothering me. Why don't the angels like Lucifer use their true forms on earth? His goal is basically the eradication of the human species on planet earth right? So, an easy way would be using his true form. As we know most humans can't tolerate the brilliance/radiance of the angel-form(eye bursting etc.) - this seems to be an easy solution.

So, I was wondering whether if I missed anything e.g., if there were any rules stated as to why he couldn't take his true form etc. (I know the real reason is the budgetary issue of being on CW). Was wandering whether there is any narrative plotline explanation for this?

Comment: Presumably if he tried to kill all humans simply by being visible it would very quickly attract attention to what he's doing, and he'd be stopped in some way before getting very far.

Comment: Lucifer is not the top "dog" for the most of season 5. In fact, he is quite vulnerable and still gathering strength. Revealing himself would get multiple angels on his as*, which would lead to his death. During his first rebellion, Lucifer was leader of legions of fallen angels. Most of them are still in Hell and stuck there. Heavenly Host, his main opposition, still numbers in thousands and if he revealed himself it would have been one vs thousands.